# How to delete file after pushed the commit?

Tags: git, github

I want to delete a specific file after pushing the commit and changing still locally **not pushed to GitHub.**

[image: Shot]

I'm trying this

```
git log path/to/file.txt

git checkout 3cdc61015724f9965575ba954c8cd4232c8b42e4 /path/to/file.txt
```

But not work with me!

Comment: rm app.abb then git add app.abb then git commit then git push

Comment: @pero_hero thanks for the comment, I just solve it by using `git reset --soft HEAD^` then delete the `app.abb` file from the stage :)